# Error using Django model forms with multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want create a simple form in my app with foreign key. I've two databases, a is default of Django, and the other is a legacy database.

The message of error that show is this: **Table 'django.customer' doesn't exist**. But I want select my other database, not Django. How I do this?

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from register.models import Customer

class Service(models.Model):
    # ..
    customer = models.ForeignKey('register.Customer', db_column='customer')
    # ..
```

This is other model in other app.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    codigo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

Both apps are in other database and not of Django.

My settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'django',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'my-user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my-password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    },
    'other-database': {
        'NAME': 'other-database',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'my-user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my-password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

In the HTML I put this:

```
{{ form_service }}
```

This my forms.py

```
from attendance.models import Service
from register.models import Customer
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class FormService(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('my_fields', 'my_fields', 'customer')
```

And this my views.py

```
def service(request):
    form_service = FormService()
    return render(request, 'service.html', {'form_service': form_service})
```

I think that the error is here. Perhaps I've had to define my other database, it should select in Django database.

I tried this, but not worked.

```
def service(request):
    queryset = Customer.objects.using('other-database').all()
    form_service = FormService(instance = queryset)

    return render(request, 'service.html', {'form_service': form_service})
```

Comment: By `Django` database you mean default database in `settings.py` file? Do you have your second database defined in `settings.py` file?

Comment: Please be more explicit with your question name, so this can be useful to other persons with your problem.

Comment: Yes, my settings.py is with the two databases defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your code `instance = queryset` doesn't make sense, because `instance` should be a Service instance for the form, not a queryset of Customer instances.

Try setting the queryset of the field in the form's `__init__` method.

```
class FormService(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormService, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customer'].queryset = Customer.objects.using('other-database').all()

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('my_fields', 'my_fields', 'customer')
```

If that doesn't work, please update your question and post the full traceback.

Comment: I'm newbie in OOP. I tried your answer, however showed this message: **super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type**.

Comment: Sorry guy, I wrote wrong. The messages stopped.
Now my form not appear in my template.

Comment: The code above shouldn't make the form disappear, as long as you have kept `form_service = FormService()` in the view. You haven't written any code to process the form yet. Read through the docs on [working with forms in the view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view) to get started.

Comment: It was appearing before, when I removed the customer of my fields in forms.py.

Comment: From the information you've given, I can't see why the form disappeared. Hope you figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, no problem, but I don't understand why I've define my other database? When I do a select, I don't need this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91658/discussion-between-rodrigo-boniatti-and-alasdair).